# How to check input value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, logical-operators

This is my handleSearch function and i am checking if inputvalue is empty it shouldn't go further and hit my getSearch call, but sometimes if i backspace inputvalue quickly it console.logs(empty) as expected and instead of stopping it goes further n hits getSearch call below.

**How to make it work correctly if inputvalue is empty.**

```
  const handleSearch = async (value) => {
    setSearchTerm(value);

    if (value.length <= 0 || value === "") {
      console.log("empty");
      setSearchResult([]);
      return;
    }

    console.log("value", value);
    const searchRes = await getSearch(value, 0);
    console.log("searchRes", searchRes);
    setSearchResult(searchRes);
  };
```

Comment: When do you call `handleSearch`? onchange of a text input?

Comment: Yes its onChange of a text input

Comment: I guess, you notice that it goes beyond the if clause, because of `console.log("value", value);`, right? Are you sure, that when that gets logged, it isn't from a previous function call? Is the number of "value" logs the same as the number of function calls?

Comment: It should not even console.log("value",value) if  if condition is met right as i am returning it.

Comment: That's why I am asking, if the number of calls is the same as the number of "value" logs. If you have 10 calls, but 9 "value" and 1 "empty" log, then it works as intended, but if you have 10 "value" logs, then it doesn't. So, which one is it?

Comment: eg if i write n and backspace to clear it 1st log is n so it calls and second log is empty but it still calls getSearch with value n.
When it logs empty  the 2nd console.log("value,value) gets skipped, it calls getSearch with value n and 3rd console.log("searchRes",searchRes) is printed

Comment: Sounds like `setSearchResult` is async and returns the result after the second call has logged "empty", and it then logs "value" from the first call.

Comment: If i backspace slowly like 1 by 1 it gives empty stops correctly but if i clear all at once it does behave like u said i guess.
What to do to prevent it ? I dont want to use onClick

Comment: [Marat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74385733/9038475) has two ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simulated your situation in the [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-snow-3jvcol?file=/src/App.js), because you use async method, when you type too fast, the first few async functions are still queued.

The best way is to use `debounce`, it can also [improve the performance of your application](https://dev.to/myogeshchavan97/using-debouncing-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-application-s-search-functionality-31j7). Please refer [here](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useDebounce.md). You can download
[react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use) directly and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not call getSearch when the value is empty string, but it calls search before that (with previous value), and you get async result after. You have a couple of options to prevent this:

1. You can do the search on button click, not on input change
2. You can implement [debounce](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086) for your requests (so the request only goes to server when user stopped writing)

First is easier, second is better for learning